# Should I set document version field to be part of a primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, table, surrogate-key

Should I set document version as a primary key 
I am working on a document management system, and I have these two tables representing part of the whole tables.

[image]

On the DocumentVersion table I have set the primary key to be (version + documentID) . so can anyone advice if this is a  recommended approach where the documentID is of type int while the version is of type decimal(5,2) ? or it is better if I create a new field and set it as the primary key inside the DocumentVersion table?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `DocumentVersion` table makes sense to me.  The two columns well define the Document by the `DocumentID` relationship to the Primary Key on `Document` and the `Version` makes a unique entry for `DocumentVersion`.  (Just as the name implies.)

There is no problem having a primary key that included two different data types, so an `INT` and a `DECIMAL(5,2)` will coexist happily in the same Primary Key.

What you do want to **avoid** is having a join between mismatched data types, such as joining a `VARCHAR(10)` with an `INT`. This will likely result in problems with the join performance even when all the data is clean.  (And, of course, a `VARCHAR` can hold strings that would not convert to `INT` which would be another class of problem.)

**EDIT:** Depending upon your usage, a surrogate PK column `DocumentVersionID` could be beneficial for other tables to reference.  However, for integrity of tracking the versions, the **`DocumentID`,`Version`** should at least be enforced by a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

E.g.  `... CONSTRAINT Unique_DocumentVersion UNIQUE (DocumentID, Version);`

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing wrong with your schema, personally I would create a separate `DocumentVersionId` column for similar reasons to those listed in [Why should I create an ID column when I can use others as key fields?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields?rq=1):

- Joins based on a single integer are more efficient than those involving multiple columns. Your schema doesn't show any other tables joining to `DocumentVersion`, but to me it seems fairly likely that you will want to add one eventually.
- An auto-incrementing `DocumentVersionId` is a good choice for a clustered index.